# The best Question Grand reopening - Gather

Tags: discussion

my question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262321/large-numbers-in-physics was closed. Two users gave a "reason". The first one didnt make any sense at all. And the second one I have adjusted my question to take care of.

So now could we reopen? If not, can I get a reason? I dont get what people have agaisnt my question. I get at first 10 different reasons for closing, why are people so interested in trying to find flaws with the question instead of answering it?

You can do this to any question, if it got any math, just say its not physics, if it got some QFT, just say its not rigorous so it doesnt make sense

Comment: I expect people were impressed by your tact and diplomacy

Comment: So this is why they make up reasons and vote to close? I have autsim I wouldnt understand, it just doesnt make sense to me

Answer (score 6):

I voted to close your question because it is unclear what is being asked:

What constitutes a "number in physics"? Does any dimensionless combination of physical parameters count? How could one possibly determine the *correct* answer to this question? What does *"No numbers which can be defined strictly mathematically is allowed."* mean? *Every* number can be "defined strictly mathematically - numbers are a mathematical concept after all.

Beyond these technical problems with the question, it's unclear what the goal here is - why is this question *physically interesting*? (This alone would not be grounds for closing, as long as the question is about physics) Often one can determine what a user is really trying to ask if their motivation is known, but you've given us nothing of the sort.

Comment: I could answer everything and explain but i doubt it will be reopened. The problem seems to be that the reader simply dont understand the question, but so it is with most questions on this site and one should approach a question humble not with a know it all this question doesnt make sense attitude.

Comment: @Loffen If, as you say, *the problem seems to be that the reader simply doesn't understand the question*, then that is where your problem lies. If a question is unclear, it's liable to be closed until it's clarified.